# @OnetoMany relationship only accepting one object instead of a list in the column [SPRING]

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity-relationship

I'm having trouble with a relationship between two attributes (owners and pets: one owner should be able to have many pets) in spring, this is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="owners_table")
public class Owners {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String email;
    
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String address;
     
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="id")
    @JsonManagedReference(value="pet-owners")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Pets> pets;

    
    public Owners() {
        
    }
    @JsonCreator
    public Owners(Integer id, String name, String phoneNumber, String email, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }
```

(plus the getters and setters)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pets_table")
public class Pets {
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private Date birthDate;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference(value="pet-owners")
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Owners owner;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="walk_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value="pet-walks")
    private DogWalking walk;
    

    public Pets() {
    }
    
    @JsonCreator
    public Pets(String name, String breed, Date birthDate,  Owners owner , Integer id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.id = id;
    }
```

(plus getters and setters)

I believe this is the only part of the code that matters for this question, but if you need anything else you can tell me and I'll put it here.

**I'm gonna explain the problem in action now:**
I had this owner in my database:
(my request: localhost:8080/owners/6)

```
 {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Lucas Calado",
        "phoneNumber": "(83) 98326-9273",
        "email": "lucasthecalado@gmail.com",
        "address": "Rua Bancário João Luiz , 92",
        "pets": []
}
```

and then I added one pet to the pet list:
(my request: localhost:8080/pets/insert)

```
  {
                "name": "Fenrir",
                "breed": "Husky siberiano",
                "birthDate": "2017-03-08T03:00:00.000+00:00",
                "owner":{
                    "id":6
                }
                "walks": null
}
```

***and, until now, everything is fine***

now, if I make the same request to get the owner by id, this is whats shown to me:

```
 {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Lucas Calado",
        "phoneNumber": "(83) 98326-9273",
        "email": "lucasthecalado@gmail.com",
        "address": "Rua Bancário João Luiz , 92",
        "pets": [
            {
                "name": "Fenrir",
                "breed": "Husky siberiano",
                "birthDate": "2017-03-08T03:00:00.000+00:00",
                "id": 6,
                "walks": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

BUT, when I try to add another pet to the same owner id, it goes to the next owner id (in this case, id=7, and nothing happens to the owner that has the id 6.
(my request: localhost:8080/pets/insert)

```
{
    "name": "Roabson",
    "breed": "Pug",
    "birthDate": "2018-12-02T03:00:00.000+00:00",
    "owner":{
        "id":6
    }
}
```

my owner (id=6) stays the absolute same, with only one pet, and my next owner (id=7) recieves this pet.

Comment: There is a difference between both the insert pet requests.

Comment: @Arun Sudhakaran I'm sorry! Its because I copied from the json that was already working (owners/1) I just took the pet from inside it, but the request I had done to insert the pet was exaclty the same as the second one, I just changed the name and the breed. But I'll edit my question so it looks the same

Answer (score 0):

Try using this sample.

In Owners class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owners", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Pets> pets = new HashSet<>();
```

In Pets class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "owners_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Owners owners;
```

> It is also better not to use plural nouns for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you send a list this way, you rewrite it. You don't add an item, you rewrite the list. If you want to add, you request already exisiting items of the list, add a new one, and send this altered list.